# Servlet 500 error ClassNotFound exception

Tags: maven, servlets, intellij-idea, gson, vaadin

I'm building a web app using Vaadin and it needs to communicate with several REST APIs.  I've set it up in IntelliJ with Maven.  I was thinking for the REST client I would use GSON to parse the JSON objects I'd be receiving from the open APIs, however, the application crashes due to a servlet exception error.

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject
```

I've added the GSON dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And have tried changing the module settings from Provided to Compiled to Runtime but with no change.

I'm just stumped as to why the GSON jar appears in the project dependencies within IntelliJ using Maven but fails on run time.  I've seen references to Eclipse and including the jar in the classpath but, again, I'm using IntelliJ/Maven to build my Vaadin project and satisfy dependencies.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below dependency in your `classpath`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: appear to be getting errors related to this dependency: [INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.RichTextAreaImplIE6'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:fakepathforstackoverflow/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0/gwt-user-2.3.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/RichTextAreaImplIE6.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element to com.google.gwt.user.client.Element
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.PopupImplIE6'

Comment: looks like increasing version to 2.7 did the trick!  thanks for the suggestion!  got it from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133280/error-during-vaadin-widgetset-compilation